# Calculating a day on a specific date

Tags: language-agnostic

Is there any direct way to know the day on a specific date?

For example, take any date say 23-08-1980. Now, I want to know the day on this date (It could be any starting from Monday to Sunday).

Is there any formula or any other way to calculate this statistically?

Do not use any programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this Wikipedia page, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_the_day_of_the_week#A_tabular_method_to_calculate_the_day_of_the_week

It goes over leap years as well.

Comment: Yes, I have visited and used it but the algorithms specified do not work on some specific dates such as 1/3/1900, 1/3/1903 and alike...

Answer (score 1):

You need some meta information about the year for example the first Sunday of every month in every year, from there on you should be able to calculate the day faster.

http://www.jimloy.com/math/day-week.htm